# Where can I read Prabodha Sudhakara of Adi Shankara in English?

Tags: scripture, adi-shankaracharya, translation-request

Adi Shankaracharya's little known philosophical work is Prabodha Sudhakara. I am interested in reading it. Where can I read this work in online in English?

Comment: What is the work about?

Comment: Looks like only English translation is [here](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/prabodhasudhakara-nectar-ocean-of-enlightenment-IDG442/) and it is not available online.

Comment: @Ikshvaku it is a work by him combining Bhakti and Vedanta.

Comment: @The Destroyer you mean English translation is available but it is not digitalized

Comment: @NaveenKick Yes.